# How to append dict to a dict in python and export to a json file

Tags: python, json

at each function call, I would like to append a new dictionary to a json file and save everything to an updated file.

Basically I would like to create a json file that every time the function is executed, is updated with the information of the new order.

The procedure I follow is this:

1. I load the json file in a python object
2. I add the new order to the python object
3. I rewrite the json file with the new python object

The problem, however, is that it seems to overwrite the result at every iteration

The code I wrote is this:

```
import json
from pathlib import Path

def exportOrderJson(filename,ordine,data,status,business,product,quantity,amount):

    filename += ".json"
    JSON_PATH = Path(filename)

    # If file not exists, I create it and inizialize
    if (not(JSON_PATH.is_file())):
        order_dict_inizialize = {"Orders": {}}
        with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(order_dict_inizialize, outfile, indent=2)

    # New dict to append
    order_dict = { 
                "order_id": ordine,
                "data": data,
                "status": status,
                "is_business": business,
                "quantity": quantity,
                "amount": amount
            }

    # json object to python object
    with open(filename,"r") as json_file:  
        obj = json.load(json_file)

    # I update the python dict with the new dict
    obj["Orders"].update(order_dict)
    
    # I write the updated dict to the json file
    with open(filename, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(obj, outfile, indent=2)


# Execute function
for i in range(3):
    exportOrderJson(........)
```

The output on file is:

```
{
  "Orders": {
    "order_id": "3",
    "data": "xxx",
    "status": "xxx",
    "is_business": "xxx",
    "quantity": "xxx",
    "amount": "xxx"
  }
}
```

What I would like is:

```
{
  "Orders": {
    "order_id": "1",
    "data": "xxx",
    "status": "xxx",
    "is_business": "xxx",
    "quantity": "xxx",
    "amount": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "order_id": "2",
    "data": "xxx",
    "status": "xxx",
    "is_business": "xxx",
    "quantity": "xxx",
    "amount": "xxx"
  },
  {
    "order_id": "3",
    "data": "xxx",
    "status": "xxx",
    "is_business": "xxx",
    "quantity": "xxx",
    "amount": "xxx"
  },
}
```

Comment: Expected output is neither a proper `dict` nor a `json` format.

Comment: No I meant the _What I would like is_ part. `{"Orders":{}, {}, {}}` is not a valid python object. Perhaps you want the value to be an array: `{"Orders":[{}, {}, {}]}`?

Comment: You can either have a list or dictionaries whose values are strings or a dictionary whose value is a list of dictionaries. You must choose and your initial value you write to the file even though you have only a single order must reflect that choice.That is, either `[]` or `{"Orders": []}`. Personally, I would go for the list of dictionaries (option 1)